# showing key along side data json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Hi I have a dynamic json the details in it changes in every product so I wanna show keys along side their corresponding data
any example would be great I am struggling with this. sample json in appDetails wanna show all the keys like systemoverview,benefits, mainFeatures and their data.

In next product it will be changed but appdetails will remain same.

````
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: TestScreen()));
}

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestScreen> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  List<AppDetails>? details = [];
  final Map<String, dynamic> json = {
    "name": "TestingApp",
    "category": "Production",
    "subcategory": "Productivity",
    "imageUrl": "Testing-Banner.jpg",
    "logo": "PI.png",
    "description": "Testing is an application for easy & effective Inspection",
    "appDetails": [
      {
        "systemOverview": "https:url.com",
        "multiDeviceSupport": [
          {"item1": "Multi-Device"},
          {"item2": "Multi-Lingual"},
          {"item3": "Multi-Database"}
        ],
        "mainFeatures": [
          {"feature1": "Testing"},
          {"feature2": "Ease"},
          {"feature3": "Select failure "}
          
        ],
        "benefits": [
          {"benfits1": "Easy & quick solution "},
          {"benefits2": "Go paperless "},
        personnel’s"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final data = AppDetailModel.fromJson(json);
    details = data.appDetails;
    List<AppDetails>? parseCategorizedBooksJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => [
          for (var detai in json.values)
            for (var de in detai) AppDetails.fromJson(de)
        ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: details?.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final detail = details?[index];

            return buildProduct(detail);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget buildProduct(AppDetails? detail) => Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: (detail?.benefits ?? []).map((e) {
          final index = (detail?.benefits ?? []).indexOf(e);
          return Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(width: 20, child: Text('${index + 1}.')),
              Text('${e.label}'),
            ],
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );

class AppDetailModel {
  String? name;
  String? category;
  String? subcategory;
  String? imageUrl;
  String? logo;
  String? description;
  List<AppDetails>? appDetails;

  AppDetailModel(
      {this.name,
      this.category,
      this.subcategory,
      this.imageUrl,
      this.logo,
      this.description,
      this.appDetails});

  AppDetailModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    category = json['category'];
    subcategory = json['subcategory'];
    imageUrl = json['imageUrl'];
    logo = json['logo'];
    description = json['description'];
    if (json['appDetails'] != null) {
      appDetails = <AppDetails>[];
      json['appDetails'].forEach((v) {
        appDetails!.add(AppDetails.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['name'] = name;
    data['category'] = category;
    data['subcategory'] = subcategory;
    data['imageUrl'] = imageUrl;
    data['logo'] = logo;
    data['description'] = description;
    if (appDetails != null) {
      data['appDetails'] = appDetails!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class AppDetails {
  String? systemOverview;
  List<Label>? multiDeviceSupport;
  List<Label>? mainFeatures;
  List<Label>? benefits;

  AppDetails(
      {this.systemOverview,
      this.multiDeviceSupport,
      this.mainFeatures,
      this.benefits});

  AppDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    systemOverview = json['systemOverview'];
    if (json['multiDeviceSupport'] != null) {
      multiDeviceSupport = <Label>[];
      json['multiDeviceSupport'].forEach((v) {
        multiDeviceSupport!.add(Label.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['mainFeatures'] != null) {
      mainFeatures = <Label>[];
      json['mainFeatures'].forEach((v) {
        mainFeatures!.add(Label.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['benefits'] != null) {
      benefits = <Label>[];
      json['benefits'].forEach((v) {
        benefits!.add(Label.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['systemOverview'] = systemOverview;
    if (multiDeviceSupport != null) {
      data['multiDeviceSupport'] =
          multiDeviceSupport!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (mainFeatures != null) {
      data['mainFeatures'] = mainFeatures!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (benefits != null) {
      data['benefits'] = benefits!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Label {
  String? label;

  Label({this.label});

  Label.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    label = json['label'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['label'] = label;
    return data;
  }
}
```
````

currently What I am doing right now

Answer (score 0):

so taking your example:

```
final map = {
    
    "appDetails": [
      {
        "systemOverview": "https:url.com",
        "multiDeviceSupport": [
          {"label": "Multi-Device"}
          
        ],
        "mainFeatures": [
          {"label": "Testing"}
         
        ],
        "benefits": [
          {"label": "Easy & quick solution "},
          {"label": "Go paperless "}
        
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
```

we can get both the key and value using the entries like this:

```
map!["appDetails"]![0].entries.forEach((e) {
    
    print("${e.key}, ${e.value}");
  });
```

This code will print this result:

```
systemOverview, https:url.com
multiDeviceSupport, [{label: Multi-Device}]
mainFeatures, [{label: Testing}]
benefits, [{label: Easy & quick solution }, {label: Go paperless }]
```

it will print the key along with it's value, you can use this sample to achieve your result.

Comment: and how to show the values of inner array like multidevice support using the above mention code ?

Comment: you can iterate over them with some for loop or forEach

Comment: I have updated the body of question with what I am implementing please If you can review that and help me updating that

Comment: I see that you already modeled the json into a model class, if what you're asking me is showing all keys in the Map with the nested ones, then the Map should be itertaed with an algorithmn then modelize it.

Comment: yup I have a model class from which I am calling AppDetail that is List 
currently what I modifiy I am specifically calling detail.benefits it show all the benefits similarily If I do detail.systemoverview it show the data correspondence to that 's not something I wanna do the example you have share above is something I wanna achieve
but lacking enough knowledge to use different loops etc to show the data of nested array.

Comment: Also I have modified the requirements though it's complex but If you can just run on dart pad and can help me modifying it will be so kind of you because I am stuck in this thing from last week.

Comment: I tried to extract all nested key/value to the outside of the map, but as you see they all have that "label" key so every one replaces the previous one with the label key

Comment: do you want to achive that every key like systemOverview will have a List value containing all labels for it

Comment: like this example on dartpad

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anasfik/8668cd95d434a85b0bab0f8b1247547f

Comment: take that code and try it on dartpad, and tell me is it suitable for your case ?

Comment: I have updated the json hopefully it  will make some sense i.e. key is changing everytime so 
show all the data inside benefits along side key like this

label1: "Testing

Comment: because I don't what will be the label so consider key as heading and label and it's text

Comment: what you have share is something I was looking for if you can modify bit more showing data of benefits in Text along side it's content would look good instead of showing in array and object

Comment: oh so they all should be listed in the map, wait

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anasfik/632c0a33136cf6a82799329a1528c3f7

Comment: is this suitable for you ?

Comment: Looks good A question here you are showing of multidevice support in json object how to show data outside json object like text

Comment: if you're planning to loop or modelize this new Map, then you should consider letting it like this so you can write a piece of code that will handle it on all cases

Answer (score 0):

print all keys of JSON data

```
var data = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
print(data.keys.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do somthing like this

```
Column(children: 
          data['appDetails']
              .map(
                (system) => Column(
                  children: system.entries
                      .map<Widget>(
                        (systemeEntry) => systemeEntry.value is String
                            ? Row(
                                children: [
                                  Text("${systemeEntry.key}: "),
                                  Expanded(child: Text(systemeEntry.value)),
                                ],
                              )
                            : systemeEntry.value is List
                                ? Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(" ${systemeEntry.key} => "),
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Column(
                                          children:
                                              systemeEntry.value is List
                                                  ? systemeEntry.value
                                                      .map<Widget>(
                                                        (detail) => Column(
                                                            children: [
                                                              ...detail
                                                                  .entries
                                                                  .map(
                                                                    (detailEntry) =>
                                                                        Row(
                                                                            children: [
                                                                          Text(" ${detailEntry.key}: "),
                                                                          Text(detailEntry.value),
                                                                        ]),
                                                                  )
                                                                  .toList()
                                                            ]),
                                                      )
                                                      .toList()
                                                  : [const SizedBox()],
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )
                                : const SizedBox(),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
)
```

Comment: will you please modify it according to the code above shared 
Because Having a slightly confusion